# In editing mode, there are layers, as in the object mode?

Tags: edit-mode, layers

In edit mode, you can easily hide or show interfering elements. But when you switch to the object mode, they are displayed. How can they be hidden in both cases? But let them remain in the model.

Comment: You can't. Hiding in edit mode is just to help modeling tasks or else, just to be able to better see/select visibile geometry.